# Assigning a string result to a list

Tags: python, string, list

I can't find the code to assign a string to a list and then name it.

The question states:
Now split some_string by commas and assign the result to a list named mammals. Print mammals to verify that your split worked correctly.

```
some_string = "cat,dog,bear,chipmunk,squirrel,bat,groundhog"

print(some_string)
```

Comment: By google searching "Python split", I get [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp), it should be able to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What they're asking you to do is:

```
mammals = some_string.split(',')
print(mammals)
```

This way `mammals` becomes a list named mammals and `=` performs the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> mammals = some_string.split(",")
>>> print(mammals)
['cat', 'dog', 'bear', 'chipmunk', 'squirrel', 'bat', 'groundhog']
```